# Why is htop and Activity Monitor showing different even when running htop as sudo?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, homebrew, memory, activity-monitor

I have installed `htop` using homebrew on an M1 Macbook Air. Below, one can see that the used memory reported by `htop` and Activity Monitor are different.

I am aware of other answers in this website where people recommend `htop` to be invoked under `sudo` privileges: `sudo htop`. In theory, this should make them both match. However, the screenshot below was taken just after having invoked it under `sudo`.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The two programs are simply displaying different things. One says "Mem" as an explanation and the other says "Memory Used" - they're not the same thing.

If you take values for "App Memory" and "Wired Memory" from Activity Monitor and add them up, you get the same value as the "Mem" value in `htop`.

Comment: The formula isn't exact. In my case, htop shows 14G used, App 15.4 + Wired 2.9 totals to over 17G. But Compressed shows 5.6 G. So, who knows... Activity Monitor shows Total Memory Used: 24.5 G for me in this case. Subtracting all compressed memory still results in 18 G, so... no match either.

Comment: My App Memory alone is more than what htop is showing...