RAM usage discrepancy between Activity Monitor and htop in MacBook Pro
I don't understand why values are different, which one is right? I attach screenshots, running in MacBook Pro with M3.



Both are "right". Just measuring/counting in different ways.  See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435723/why-is-htop-and-activity-monitor-showing-different-even-when-running-htop-as-sud

With 96GB of RAM, is it even concerning?!

@Gilby I see, but I wonder what value I should consider "real" used and free memory, for example I wouldn't count cache as real used memory as it is actually available for process than need more ram.

See my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460827/macbook-pro-frequently-running-excessive-ram-swap-despite-available-ram. Also "real" may not be the best word to use as "real memory" has particular meaning on Unix and Unix derived memory systems - Activity Monitor has a column for Real Memory.  I think Activity Monitor makes a reasonable stab with Memory Used even if it is not defined anywhere and is not the sum of the App,Wired,Com as implied by the graphic.
